# DropBox files not being overwritten

Tags: python, dropbox-api

I have some code that I have used to upload files from a windows file to one I have created on DropBox via the DropBox API. This works fine the first time the files are uploaded, but the intention is that this code will overwrite existing files that have been stored there with updated data.

I've added the parameters 'overwrite' and 'parent_rev' to facilitate this. I've set 'overwrite' to 'True' which should allow the existing file of the same name to be overwritten. I've also set 'parent_rev' to the value of the item 'rev' which is part of each file's metadata dictionary which can be accessed via the API, but the files are not being overwritten.

The modified date/time field in the metadata is not being updated the analogous field displayed on screen next to the DropBox file on their site is not being updated either. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
import dropbox
import fileinput
import sys
import glob

client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient('')

datastores = ['PlayerStatsBySeasonByComp']

for data in datastores:

    path = ("C:\\Python27\\Whoscored\\WhoScoredData\\",data,"\*.txt")
    path = ''.join(path)

    for name in glob.glob(path):

        print name

        f = open(name, 'rb')
        f2 = name.split('\\')
        f2 = f2[5]           
        f3 = ('Football Data/',data,'/',f2)
        f3 = ''.join(f3)
        file_metadata = client.metadata(f3)
        the_rev = file_metadata['rev']

        response = client.put_file(f3, f, overwrite=True, parent_rev = the_rev)
```

Comment: One quick thing to check... make sure the actual content you're uploading is different. Dropbox will pretty much ignore the change if you reupload the same content.

Comment: Also, check the response, and if your intent is to unconditionally overwrite, `overwrite=True` is all you need. I believe `parent_rev` is simply getting ignored.

Comment: I was just about to make the comment smarx did - make sure the files are actually different. This fooled me for a bit.

Comment: thanks for the replies all. During the testing I have not been using different files, which probably explains why they weren't showing an updated modified date. I didn't realise this would be the case. What I have decided to do in the end was to delete the old file right before uploading a new one. That way I can see straight away whether the file has changed or not. The code is marginally slower in execution, but I can live with that.